# Newlines get stripped in SQL after datatable update

Tags: c#, sql-server, newline

I have a datatable that gets modified by having the html stripped out. During the html strip if a `<br>`, `<p>` or `<li>` is encountered they are replace with `System.Environment.NewLine`. I am logging ever instance of the html strip process to a text file and the formatting looks fine in the log (all CRLF are preserved). However when the update method is called on the datatable and the data gets sent to the database the CRLF characters are all gone.

Code snippet:

```
public static class HtmlStripper
{
    static Regex _htmlRegex = new Regex("<.*?>", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    static Regex _liRegex = new Regex("<li>", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    static Regex _brRegex = new Regex("<(br)?(BR)?\\s?/?>\\s*", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    static Regex _pRegex = new Regex("</?[phPH].*?>\\s*", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    public static string StripTagsRegexCompiled(string source)
    {
        string noPorH = _pRegex.Replace(source, System.Environment.NewLine);
        string noBr = _brRegex.Replace(noPorH, System.Environment.NewLine);
        string noLi = _liRegex.Replace(noBr, System.Environment.NewLine + "t- ");
        return _htmlRegex.Replace(noLi, string.Empty);
    }

}
```

Comment: Some code snipits would be helpful in answering your question.

Comment: are you checking the data in the database using Sql Server Management Studio? If so, it strips out the newlines when displaying it (but the data is still correct)

Comment: I copied the data from SSMS into Notepad++ and the CRLF characters are all gone.

Comment: @DanAndrews So are you saying that if I use this data in an application it will preserve the line feeds?

Comment: So yes it is SSMS after all. I queried the DB from the application and displayed the data and the CRLF characters are there. You learn something everyday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSMS removes CRLF in the data grid - however they are still there in the database.  You can prove this by pressing `CTRL-T` which turns your results to TEXT instead of in the GRID.  You can then press `CTRL-D` to return to having your results in a GRID.

You can test this with:

```
SELECT  'Not' + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) + 'Together'
```

First by showing the result in the GRID:

```
(No Column name)
Not  Together
```

Then in the TEXT result:

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

-------------
Not

Together

(1 row(s) affected)


SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
```